# Optimization sql about group by and having

Tags: sql, optimization, group-by, common-table-expression, having

I have a common question about how to do a query efficiently.

| id | time |
| --- | --- |
| d048533c-92d2-11eb-8dbb-fa163e962e00 | 1617272028623 |
| 6b5b455e-92d3-11eb-8dbb-fa163e962e00 | 1617272279382 |
| 024d0a5e-92d3-11eb-8dbb-fa163e962e00 | 1617272106615 |

We Have a table like above. We want to filter out IDs according to the following conditions:

1. If two or more IDs have time within a 3-minute period,we call them a group over two.
2. we hava 10000 ids and we want to find all groups over ten.

Here is my answer:

```
SELECT B.ID FROM TEMP B,TEMP A
WHERE B.ID != A.ID
AND (B.TIME <= A.TIME + 180000 AND B.TIME >= A.TIME - 180000) GROUP BY B.ID HAVING COUNT(*) >= 9;
```

Is there any more efficient method?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "filter out ids . . . More than 10 IDs correspond to the time within a 3-minute period".  Your data has no column called `id` and **two** columns with the `_id` suffix.

Comment: sorry,i have fixed the error

Answer (score 0):

If you want the 10th id that occurs within 3 minutes, then you can use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(time, 9) over (order by time) as time_9
      from t
     ) t
where time < time_9 + 3 * 60 * 1000;
```

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want.  But the key idea is to use window functions in general -- and `lag()` in particular -- instead of a self-join.

The performance should be much, much better.

EDIT:

If you want to find all rows that are part of a group that has at least 10 in a 3 minute period, then find the first -- and then determine if a "first" such row is within 9 rows of any other row:

```
with t9 as (
      select t.*,
             (case when time_9 < time + 3 * 60 * 1000 then 1 else 0 end) as group_start
      from (select t.*,
                   lead(time, 9) over (order by time) as time_9
            from t
           ) t
     )
select t9.*
from (select t9.*,
             sum(group_start) over (order by time rows between 9 preceding and current row) as in_group_flag
      from t9
     ) t9
where in_group_flag > 0
```

Comment: it's an enlightening answer. The point is we need a method to find all ids meets the conditions